# Unable to use CoreWebView2 from .NET6 app

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, webview2

I see the potential of webview2 in winForms, and i'm trying to insert it into a .net6 controller.

The winform code is that one:

```
Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 mySilentEdgeBrowser = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
            mySilentEdgeBrowser.NavigationStarting += SilentEdgeBrowser_CoreWebView2NavigationStarting;
            mySilentEdgeBrowser.NavigationCompleted += SilentEdgeBrowser_CoreWebView2NavigationCompleted;
            mySilentEdgeBrowser.Source = baseAddress;
            await mySilentEdgeBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
```

My problem is obviusly that i cannot import the System.Windows.Forms inside my .net6 controller, but of what i understand of webView2 all that i need can be done with CoreWebView2, so if there is a way to instance it in my controller the job is done. I search online for it but with no luck, there is an aviable solution?

***EDIT*:**
Puppeteer and similar software are not an option, the site detect an automation.

Thanks,
L-

Comment: But why do you want to do this?)

Comment: To open a webpage that contains a lot a javascript and retrieve it's content after the execution of js code. Whit httpclient and other ways i got the source before the js stuff.

Comment: And how will you check if for instance a 'cookie consent' comes up, blocking the javascript - when you can't see it?

Comment: In my specific situation i already try using puppeter and it doesn't work. Is detected as an automation from the destintion website and redirect to a support page. The main point of webView2 is that is a full feature edge browser, and can load the page correctly (tried in a .net 6.0 desktop standalone app and it works)

Answer (score 0):

I think in theory it is possible to do that, but I would argue that it would be far from optimal solution. You can use either [puppeteer](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) or [playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet) to achieve the same functionality. Both AFAIK allow to wait for js execution and/or execute custom js scripts.